# Pandas DataFrame Read Skipping line XXX: expected X fields, saw Y

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I can't figure out what's wrong with the csv file I'm trying to load:

I get error messages such as this:
`b'Skipping line 2120260: expected 6 fields, saw 8\n'`

But when I view the lines, they look ok to me. See below -- (I am going to press enter after each tab \t  to make it easier to read).

Line 2,120,260 (failing):

`['user_000104\t
2005-09-12T06:25:50Z\t
a019a8cf-2601-4a81-b3c3-7b279a873713\t
Anne Clark\t
8f8e6bc0-c3c0-4062-875a-773a1de6206f\t
Empty Me']`

Line 9,000 (not failing):

`['user_000001\t
2008-06-15T17:28:31Z\t
a3031680-c359-458f-a641-70ccbaec6a74\t
Steve Reich\t
2991db42-3b19-4344-a340-605ac3fbd7e9\t
Drumming: Part Iv']`

If anyone wants to try it out for themselves, download this:

http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~ocelma/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-1K.html

and run:
 `inpFile2 = pd.read_csv(fPath, sep='\t', error_bad_lines= False)`

to generate the error. And:

`def checkRow(path,N):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        print("This is the line.")
        print(next(itertools.islice(csv.reader(f), N, None)))`

to view the error row (pass in the file path and the row you are interested in). Make sure you import csv and import itertools.

Comment: Can you upload line 2120250 to 2120270 as a separate file to somewhere? That file is huge to download.

Comment: Ok some further updates. Using emacs I have definitely proven that the line above is on row 2120452 (at least according to emacs) which must mean the code I'm using above is not the correct  ..bear with me still editing

Comment: ...continued   
2) The row that emacs says is the faulty one looks completly ok too though
3) If in emacs I use Go to Buffer Position rather than go to Line number is and type in 2120260, it takes me to row 17084. This row does have 1 field missing however in that case the error message doesn't make sense. I may try and cut chunks of the text out into a separate file to figure out which line is the true incorrectrow

Comment: Ok so mystery deepens. I tried extracting all the possible suspects and then some to a new smaller file but that file loads fine.

Comment: Note: I couldn't do Allen's request until I could find a portion of the file that actually contained the error, so it was in the process of doing so whereby I split and re-split the csv file using the command line split tool that I managed to home in on the error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I manged to get the bottom of it.

The solution is to use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` as a parameter in the read_csv command.
`inpFile = pd.read_csv(fPath, sep='\t', error_bad_lines= False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

And the reason for that is the existence of a double quote in one of the fields which is causing Pandas to get confused so need to tell it not to look out for strings/quotes. Making the above change *seems* to have loaded it.

Answer (score 5):

In case you simply want to "hide" the warnings for row errors, you can use parameter `warn_bad_lines=False` , as opposed to default value True, more info here: [pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.2/io.html)