# Count of lines from Pandas read_csv returning less than expected

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas read_csv shape[0] or len(index) functions returns 19929388 rows of a 20 million lines file I have on my computer. But the powershell command bellow returns 20 million. Is there something wrong with my code?

Powershell - Returns 20000000

```
[int]$LinesInFile = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'File.csv'
 while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $LinesInFile++ }
```

Python - Returns 19929388

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=(False), delimiter='|', header=None)    
index = df.shape[0]
print(index)
```

Comment: By default the `skip_blank_lines` parameter is `True` for [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Which will "skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values."

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, the first column of my file is always populated. Anyways I've tried `skip_blank_lines=False` and got the same result (19929388).

Comment: Using `engine='python'` I've got some errors like _Skipping line 182405: '|' expected after '"'_. I don't think this make sense, since I'm not passing quoting as parameter on read_csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
Pandas was skipping some lines because of unclosed double quotes marks, even though I was not declaring qualifiers for my file.

Just adding **quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE** on pd.read_csv() solved it.

This post helped me out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891391/pandas-dataframe-read-skipping-line-xxx-expected-x-fields-saw-y)