# Whenever I am trying to read this csv using Pandas, it is skipping lines. How to read csv without skipping lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

[Updated CSV] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK8f1.png)

```
INSURER(S) AFFORDING COVERAGE ,NAIC ,
INSURER A Texas Mutual Insurance Company ,22945 ,
INSURER B Champlain Specialty Insurance Company ,16834 ,
INSURER C Clear Blue Insurance Company, Inc. ,28860 ,
INSURER RSUI Indemnity Company ,22314 ,
INSURER E Navigators Insurance Company ,42307 ,
INSURER Westchester Surplus Lines Insurance Company ,10172 ,
```

I am trying to apply this
`df_insr = pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=False)`

I want to load entire CSV, without skipping any lines.

Comment: "*This is the CSV*" <- no, this is an image. That said, `read_csv` should not remove any line. Please provide a reproducible example **as text**

Comment: I am getting this error
b'Skipping line 6: expected 3 fields, saw 4\n'

Comment: Please provide the real CSV file (as a link or as text)

Comment: for reference, you can check this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891391/pandas-dataframe-read-skipping-line-xxx-expected-x-fields-saw-y

Comment: @mozway Kindly check now.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is due to an invalid CSV file.

In the line:

```
INSURER C Clear Blue Insurance Company, Inc. ,28860 ,
```

A comma in the  company name is not properly escaped.

A workaround could be to use `<space>,` as separator:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=r'\s+,', engine='python').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                       INSURER(S) AFFORDING COVERAGE   NAIC
0           INSURER A Texas Mutual Insurance Company  22945
1    INSURER B Champlain Specialty Insurance Company  16834
2       INSURER C Clear Blue Insurance Company, Inc.  28860
3                     INSURER RSUI Indemnity Company  22314
4             INSURER E Navigators Insurance Company  42307
5  INSURER Westchester Surplus Lines Insurance Co...  10172
```